# Bulk index / create documents with elasticsearch for python

Tags: python, json, elasticsearch, bulkinsert, elasticsearch-py

I am generating a large number of elasticsearch documents with random content using python and index them with [elasticsearch-py](https://pypi.org/project/elasticsearch/).

Simplified working example (document with just one field):

```
from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch
from random import getrandbits

es_client = Elasticsearch('https://elastic.host:9200')

for i in range(1,10000000):
    document = {'my_field': getrandbits(64)}
    es_client.index(index='my_index', document=document)
```

Since this makes one request per document, I tried to speed it up by sending chunks of 1000 documents each using the `_bulk` API. However, my attempts so far have been unsuccessful.

My understanding from the docs is that you can pass an iterable to `bulk()`, so I tried:

```
from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch
from random import getrandbits

es_client = Elasticsearch('https://elastic.host:9200')

document_list = []
for i in range(1,10000000):
    document = {'my_field': getrandbits(64)}
    document_list.append(document)
    if i % 1000 == 0:
        es_client.bulk(operations=document_list, index='my_index')
        document_list = []
```

but this results in a

> elasticsearch.BadRequestError: BadRequestError(400, 'illegal_argument_exception', 'Malformed action/metadata line [1], expected START_OBJECT or END_OBJECT but found [VALUE_STRING]')

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ok, seems I have mixed up two different functions: [`helpers.bulk()`](https://elasticsearch-py.readthedocs.io/en/v8.1.2/helpers.html?highlight=bulk#elasticsearch.helpers.bulk) and [`Elasticsearch.bulk()`](https://elasticsearch-py.readthedocs.io/en/v8.1.2/api.html?highlight=bulk#elasticsearch.Elasticsearch.bulk). Either can be used to achieve what I intended to do, but they have a slightly different signature.

The `helpers.bulk()` function takes an `Elasticsearch()` object and an iterable containing the documents as parameters. The operation can be specified as `_op_type` and can be one of `index`, `create`, `delete`, or `update`. Since `_op_type` defaults to `index`, we can just omit it and simply pass the list of documents in this case:

```
from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch, helpers
from random import getrandbits

es_client = Elasticsearch('https://elastic.host:9200')

document_list = []
for i in range(1,10000000):
    document = {'my_field': getrandbits(64)}
    document_list.append(document)
    if i % 1000 == 0:
        helpers.bulk(es_client, document_list, index='my_index')
        document_list = []
```

This works fine.

The `Elasticsearch.bulk()` function can be used alternatively, but the actions/operations are mandatory as part of the iterable here and the syntax is slightly different. This means that instead of just a `dict` with the document contents, we need to have a `dict` specifying both the action (in this case `"index": {}`), as well as the body for each document. See also [`_bulk` documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/8.1/docs-bulk.html):

```
from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch
from random import getrandbits

es_client = Elasticsearch('https://elastic.host:9200')

actions_list = []
for i in range(1,10000000):
    document = {'my_field': getrandbits(64)}
    actions_list.append({"index": {}, "doc": document})
    if i % 1000 == 0:
        es_client.bulk(operations=actions_list, index='my_index')
        actions_list = []
```

This works fine as well.

I assume that both of the above generate the same `_bulk` REST API statement internally, so they should be equivalent in the end.

Comment: Thanks for sharing this. But when `my_index` does not exist, ES detects `my_field` as long integer. Then it throws error like: `"failed to parse field [my_field] of type [long] in document with id 'NfaL7YIBbLcHbjIwQM39'. Preview of field's value: '17554611566426620742'"`.  

One fix is to use `str(getrandbits(64))` to force ES to detect `keyword` type.