# I need to load a JSON file which has 100k records into Elasticsearch by using Python API. I was new to both the stack. How can i load it?

Tags: python-3.x, elasticsearch, pycharm, bulkinsert

I need to create an index and load the data into Elasticsearch. How can i do it by using python? I need to do bulk data operations. I wanted to do it without CURL.

I was using 8+ version of Elasticsearch and 3+ version of python. Need to do bulk data insertion into index without CURL.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the Python Elasticsearch documentation [here](https://elasticsearch-py.readthedocs.io/en/v8.0.1/index.html)

Otherwise you can also find help in this [Stackoverflow discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71889063/bulk-index-create-documents-with-elasticsearch-for-python)